# Laplace Transformation

Tags: calculus

> Question:
>
> $$ y''+ y'- 1=0$$
>
> and the values for $y(0) = 2, y'(0) = 3$.

Solution:

Applying Laplace transformation;

$$ L{y''} + L{y'} - L{1} = 0 $$

$$ [s^2L{y} - sy(0) - y'(0)] + [ sL{y} - y(0) ] - (-1/s)= 0$$

I'm omitting last steps because I only wanted to know that the solution till this step is either correct or not?? please help..I'm new to Laplace transformation.

Comment: Ok up to here almost.  The transform of $1$ is $\frac{1}{s}$, not $-\frac{1}{s}$

Comment: @Feliz: You should carry on. You are on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should carry on. You are on the right track. Substitute $ L(y)=Y(s) $, use the initial conditions, solve for $Y(s)$ and then find the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: @Feliz: You are very welcome.